# Cite a chapter not a page of a book

Tags: biblatex, citing, luatex

I'm trying to cite to a chapter of a in the .bib file specified book. How could I change my own cite style to change the default "p. 10" to a "ch. 10" (I only have to cite chapters)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
fleqn,                                          
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,BCOR=25mm,
english,
DIV = 12
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}
   \printunit{\addspace}
   \printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelalpha}%
    \printfield{extraalpha}}%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@online{test,
url = {http://test.test},
urldate = {2018-12-15},
title = {Test Bib},
label = {TB}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\bibliography{mybib}
\begin{document}
This is the first example\mycite[10]{test}.\\

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For compiling I'm using LuaLaTex,

Best, cortesis

Comment: You can put anything in the `postnote`. So one option is just to use `\mycite[ch.~10]{test}`

Comment: If this particular book is cited with chapters all the time, you may want to add `pagination = {chapter},` to the bib entry to automate this, so you can just type `\cite[10]{foo}` to get "ch. 10".

Comment: @moewe Or you could define a new command to cite with a chapter if you want to alternate between citing with a chapter and citing with a page.

Comment: @moewe this is the solution to what I was trying, thanks. If you could post it as an answer, I would be pleased

Comment: Another option is to use a source map to set the `pagination` to `chapter` for the entries you will cite with a chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pagination` field can be used to change the pagination type of an entry. You can try

```
@online{test,
  url        = {http://test.test},
  urldate    = {2018-12-15},
  title      = {Test Bib},
  label      = {TB},
  pagination = {chapter},
}
```

to obtain

[image: Test Bib. url: http://test.test (visited on 12/15/2018) [TB], chap. 10.]

from `\mycite[10]{test}` if you want to cite `test` with chapters all (or at least most of) the time.

For one-off changes, you can just write

```
\cite[chap.~10]{sigfridsson}
```

---

If you want to change the *default* pagination from `page` to `chapter`, you can either redefine the internal command `\blx@imc@mkpageprefix`

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\blx@imc@mkpageprefix}[1][pagination]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\blx@tempa{\blx@mkpageprefix{chapter}}%
  \iffieldundef{#1}
    {}
    {\iffieldequalstr{#1}{none}
       {\def\blx@tempa{\blx@mkpageprefix@i}}
       {\iffieldbibstring{#1}
          {\edef\blx@tempa{\blx@mkpageprefix{\thefield{#1}}}}
          {\blx@warning@entry{%
             Unknown pagination type '\strfield{#1}'}}}}%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\blx@tempa}
    {\blx@tempa[\@firstofone]}}
\makeatother
```

or set up a Biber sourcemap to add `pagination = {chapter},` to all entries without an explicit `pagination` field.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite=false]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=pagination, fieldvalue={chapter}]
    }
  }
}
```

---

There is a similar field called `bookpagination` for the prefixes/suffixes of the `pages` and `pagetotal` fields in the bibliography.

Comment: One learns something everyday. I didn't know that.

Comment: In the case of changing the defaults, perhaps mentioning the `postnote` formatting directive might be another nice third idea.

Comment: @gusbrs Mhhh yes, although I don't really have an idea for a redefined `postnote` format in this instance (at least if I want to retain the workings of the `pagination` field for all other entries). If you have a nice idea I'd love to hear it though.

Comment: Actually, I had thought of something simple like `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\iffieldint{#1}{\bibstring{chapter}~#1}{#1}}`. But, yes, you are right. Simple as it is, it is an inferior solution.